# How to prevent from multiple calling onchange functions automatically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem in the code and don't know why this is happening. I am using multiple functions call on **onchange** event in javascript. When user enters the values into the fields then other values changed by javascript functions through onchange event. But problem is that where I used an only single function in onchange event then it is working fine for calculations.
On the other hand where multiple functions used for onchange event then both function calls randomly. I need to prevent from that means I want only that single function call which is the need.
**Why both functions call and how to call them separately according to needs?**

```js
function update_net_amount(){
  var moduleprice = $('#module').val(); 
  var charges = $('#charges').val();
  var amount1 = ( ( parseInt(moduleprice) + parseInt(charges) ) );
  var discount1 = $('#discount').val();
  var netamount1 = amount1 - discount1; 
  $('#netamount1').val( netamount1 );
  alert("amc1==="+netamount1);
  }
 function update_net_amount_percentage(){
  var moduleprice = $('#module').val();
  var charges = $('#charges').val();
  var discount = $('#discount1').val();
  var amount1 = ( parseInt(moduleprice) + parseInt(charges) );
  var netamount = ( (amount1 * discount) / 100 );
  var total = amount1 - netamount;
        $('#netamount1').val( total );
  alert("amc2==="+total);
 }
 function update_net_amount_percenatge_amount(){
  var moduleprice = $('#module').val();
  var charges = $('#amcpercent').val();
  var netamount = ( (moduleprice * charges) / 100 );
  var amount2 = ( parseInt(moduleprice) + parseInt(netamount) );
  var discount = $('#discount').val();
  var nettotal = amount2 - discount;
        $('#netamount1').val( nettotal );
  alert("amc3==="+nettotal);
 }
 function update_net_amount_percenatge_amount_percentage(){
  var moduleprice = $('#module').val();
  var charges = $('#amcpercent').val();
  var netamounts = ( (moduleprice * charges) / 100 );
  var amount3 = ( parseInt(moduleprice) + parseInt(netamounts) );
  var discounts = $('#discount1').val();
  var disamount = (( amount3 * discounts ) / 100 );
  var fulltotal = amount3 - disamount;
  $('#netamount1').val(fulltotal);
  alert("amc4==="+fulltotal);
  /* discount in % subtracts from amount3 */
 }
```

```html
<html>
<div class="pro-add">
           <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="name">
             <label>Project</label>
                   <span class="txt-val"><input type="text" name="pro" value="<?php echo $data['fvprojectname']; //from database ?>" disabled="disabled" /></span>
    <label>Module</label>
                <span class="txt-val"><input type="text" name="mod" value="<?php echo $data['fvmodulename']; //from database?>" disabled="disabled" /></span><br />
                <label>AMC</label>
                   <span class="txt-val amc"><input type="text" id="charges" onchange="javascript:update_net_amount();" name="charges" placeholder="amount in rupees only." value="0" /></span>
     <label>or</label>
                   <span class="txt-val amc-per"><input type="text" name="percentcharges" id="amcpercent" onchange="javascript:update_net_amount_percenatge_amount();" placeholder="in %" />&nbsp;%</span>
       
       <div class="invoice-table">
                       <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; width:130%;">
                           <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2" class="col-all" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #00701c; color: #fff; font-weight:bold;">
                               Sr. No.</td>
                               <td rowspan="2" class="col-all" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #00701c; color: #fff; font-weight:bold;">                                   Price Per Module</td>
                               <th colspan="3" class="col-all" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #00701c; color: #fff; font-weight:bold;">
                               Amount</th>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td colspan="2" class="col-all" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #00701c; color: #fff; font-weight:bold;">
                               Discount</td>
                               <td colspan="2" class="col-all" style="border: 0px solid black; background-color: #00701c; color: #fff; font-weight:bold;">
                               Net Amount</td>
                           </tr>
                           <?php global $counter; $counter=1; ?>
                           <tr>
                         <td rowspan="2" style="border: 0px solid black;"><?php echo $counter++; ?></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                           
                           <td style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" id="module" name="price" placeholder="module price." value="<?php echo $data['fiamount']; //from database?>" onchange="javascript:update_net_amount();" /></td>
                               <td colspan="2" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" id="discount" onchange="javascript:update_net_amount();update_net_amount_percenatge_amount();" name="discount" class="set-tr" placeholder="enter discount in rupees." /> or&nbsp;&nbsp;
                               <input type="text" id="discount1" onchange="javascript:update_net_amount_percentage();update_net_amount_percenatge_amount_percentage();" name="perdiscount" class="set-tr-per" placeholder="enter discount in %." /></td>
                               <td colspan="2" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" id="netamount1" name="net" class="set-tr-net" placeholder="net amount in rupees." value="<?php //echo $data['fiamount']; ?>" onchange="javascript:update_net_amount_percenatge_amount();" /></td>
                           </tr>
                       </table>
                   </div>
                
                   <br/>
                   <span class="btn-adding"><input type="submit" name="adding" value="Save" /></span>
                   <span class="btn-cancel"><input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel"  /></span>
           </form>
       </div>
</html>
```

How to call functions calling on need the separately onchange event in javascript.

Thanks in advance, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call all the functions inline,  write your event codes in js file.

Example:

```
$('#charges').change( function(){
     update_net_amount();
})

$('#discount1').change( function(){
     update_net_amount_percentage();
     update_net_amount_percenatge_amount_percentage();
})
```

Remove  onchange events from html :

```
<input type="text" id="discount1"  name="perdiscount" class="set-tr-per" placeholder="enter discount in %." />
```

Comment: sir i am new in js. will you help me how can i place my functions in a separate file. and how can call them for onchange event in html.
please show me an example.

Comment: how to use this with a separate file.
$('#charges').change( function(){
     update_net_amount();
})

$('#discount1').change( function(){
     update_net_amount_percentage();
     update_net_amount_percenatge_amount_percentage();
})

I have used this but not calling the functions from a separate file. how to perform that. please help Sir.

Comment: Where did you put your functions ? then put `. $('#charges').change( function(){ update_net_amount(); }) $('#discount1').change( function(){ update_net_amount_percentage(); update_net_amount_percenatge_amount_percentage(); }) `   there too

Comment: Do you have jquery loaded ?

Comment: You mean jquery libarary?

Comment: I just put these functions in js file simple and then include it like this <script src="js/invoice-change.js"></script>

Is this way is correct or doing with the another way?
Please let me know.

Comment: This is correct but you have to download and  load jquery library  before invoice-change.js,  `<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: as you suggest to remove both functions from input field from onchange, like this <input type="text" id="discount1"  name="perdiscount" class="set-tr-per" placeholder="enter discount in %." />
I also load jquery but no function is calling. if i used through onchnage then it will calling on page.
why this is happening.

Comment: you should study more about jquery, this is a good resource : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Comment: What is your language ?  Maybe I can help you with Skype or TeamViewer

Comment: thanks a lot, sir. I am from India and my languages are Hindi and English.
will you help me through Teamviewer?
I will love your contribution if you are available and help me over this.
Thanks...

Comment: dear sir my skype is er.kamalhasija. will you add me and help me here. I am waiting for your response on skype.

Comment: Sure! Request send via skype

Answer (score 0):

you can chain the function. example:

```
$('selector').on('change', function(){
    firstFunction();
}

function firstFunction(){
//do your stuff
    secondFunction();
}
```

Comment: dear will you clarify your solution because I am new to js.
How I can use your functions for my code to get out from the situation $('selector').on('change', function(){
    firstFunction();
}

function firstFunction(){
//do your stuff
    secondFunction();
}